# C# XPathSelectElement() when there are multiple matches

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

We're getting unexpected results in an application I support, because the code is calling XPathSelectElement() on a path that matches multiple items. To illustrate:

```
XElement e = XElement.Parse(@"<root>
                                <child ID="123">A</child>
                                <child ID="234">B</child>
                              </root>");
Console.Out.WriteLine(e.XPathSelectElement("//child").Value);
```

In this simple case, it's returning "A". In our more complex production code, it seems to be returning the last match.

To be clear, I'm going to fix this bug with extra filtering in the XPath to make the query result unique. I don't want to depend on misusing the XPathSelectElement() method.

**However,** I'd like to be sure I understand what it's currently (incorrectly) doing. I haven't been able to find any documentation on what the expected behavior is in this case. Or is this just a non-standard behavior that you can't expect to behave consistently across environments/versions/etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for `XPathSelectElements` says (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342176%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) "Although the ordering of returned collections is not specified in the XML XPath Language 1.0 Recommendation, this extension method returns nodes in document order.". The implementation of XPathSelectElement (http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XNodeNavigator.cs,7b67622e3ab8770e) simply does `return node.XPathSelectElements(expression, resolver).FirstOrDefault();`. So based on that you should get the value of the first selected `child` element in document order. If you get a different result I would consider that a bug, but we would need to have a minimal but complete sample of XML and .NET allowing us to reproduce the result.

Comment: Thank you! My recollection was that I saw the second one defaulted, but now that I'm going through the data again I'm not able to find an example of that. There are places where the value can be changed from the default by other means, I must have been seeing those cases instead.

Answer (score 1):

The correct soultion is to be more specific in your selection. If you always want the first element you could use XPathSelectElements and First():

```
    XElement e = XElement.Parse(@"<root>
                                    <child ID=""123"">A</child>
                                    <child ID=""234"">B</child>
                                  </root>");

    Console.Out.WriteLine(e.XPathSelectElements("//child").First().Value);
```

Or you may use more specific xpath which gets the first element:

```
    XElement e = XElement.Parse(@"<root>
                                    <child ID=""123"">A</child>
                                    <child ID=""234"">B</child>
                                  </root>");

    Console.Out.WriteLine(e.XPathSelectElement("(//child)[1]").Value);
```

Comment: Yes, I know. As I stated in the question, I'm fixing it by using criteria in the Xpath to ensure it's unique. What I'm trying to learn through this question is what the current behavior does.

Comment: Sorry I don't know. Do you have a real example of xml input which will fail in you prod environment? Is the failing xml very similar to you example or is it more compex?